# how to add element to an object within an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a http request and getting back 2 sets of data. They are both an array of objects. I want to add the one element from the one array to the other. So, the one array looks like this for example:

```
[
 { name: 'Bob', age: '21'}
 { name: 'Sue', age: '34'}
]
```

Then the other one looks like this:

```
[
 { gender: 'male'}
 { gender: 'female'}
]
```

I tried joining them like this:

```
const arr = [...arr1, ...arr2];
```

But that gave me:

```
[
 { gender: 'male' }
 { gender: 'female' }
 { name: 'Bob', age: '21'}
 { name: 'Sue', age: '34'}
]
```

It should look like:

```
[
 { name: 'Bob', age: '21', gender: 'male' }
 { name: 'Sue', age: '34', gender: 'female'}
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you have some primary index/key to find from array? eg. `name` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume below two arrays have same length, and use element index for merging.

```js
let data1 = [
 { name: 'Bob', age: '21'},
 { name: 'Sue', age: '34'}
];

 
let data2=[
 { gender: 'male'},
 { gender: 'female'}
];

// basically merge objects with same index from both arrays, using object spread operator
let result = data1.map((x,i)=>({
   ...x,
   ...data2[i]
}));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: It's so unfair that you did that so quickly while I have been struggling for ages to try figure it out, haha! But seriously, thank you. That works brilliantly. Would you be willing to perhaps put a few comments in the code to just explain exactly what is happening? Especially with the x variable.

Answer (score -3):

you should use it this way

```
const arr1 = [{name:'BOB', age:'24'},{name:"jennyfer", age:'27'}]
const arr2= [{gender:'male'},{gender:'female'}]

const newArray = [{...arr1[0],gender:arr2[0].gender}, {...arr1[1],...arr2[1]}]


console.log(newArray)
```

if you need more details ask ;)